# on/off button react. I build a little voice recognition app but cant seem to work out how to get my button to turn off, once i click it, it stays on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onclick

I'm new to react so still getting my head around a few things so any help would be great.
I'm trying to get my button to turn on and off when I'm translating my voice into text.
I tried using other examples on StackOverflow but I kept getting errors so I resulted in taking it back to its original state

```
    const onClickHandler = () => {
    recognition.start();
    setIsSpeaking(true);
  };
```

currently, It stays on constantly until I refresh the page

Comment: Could you please add more details to the question?
How are you initialising state and changing it?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting state `true` every time on click.

I'm assuming you want to change state, you can achive by using like this:

```
const [isSpeaking, setIsSpeaking] = useState(false);

const onClickHandler = () => {
    setIsSpeaking(!isSpeaking);
}
```

#### Setting state when `isSpeaking` changed

If you want to make button active when you finished talking you can use React hook named `useEffect()`. It takes two parameters:

1. an effect
2. and a dependency list.

For example:

```
const [isSpeaking, setIsSpeaking] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsSpeaking(false);
}, [isSpeaking]);
```

This code will call its `effect` when any of its dependencies updated/changed. For details of [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)